# Removing Text From A TextBox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I working on a sign up page which consists of several fields, all i wanna know how can i remove/hide the text from **Password Confirmation** textbox.
when password and retype password does not match.

Here is my Code

```js
$('#txtConfirmPassword').blur(function() {
  if ($('#txtConfirmPassword').val() != $('#txtPassword').val()) {
    $('#spPasswordConfirmation').html('Password and Retype Password does not match.');
  } else {
    $('#spPasswordConfirmation').html('')
  }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
$('#spPasswordConfirmation').val('');
```

instead of

```
$('#spPasswordConfirmation').html('');
```

Comment: Thank You LulzAsh what i wanted to remove the text from the password confirmation text box, not the error message but i use the same technique(.val(' ')) for the confirmation text and it works thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.html('')` if you want, but you have to clear the box itself `#txtConfirmPassword`

<sup>See jQuery [.html(htmlString)](https://api.jquery.com/html/#html2)</sup>

```js
$('#txtConfirmPassword').blur(function() {

  let txtConfirmPassword = $('#txtConfirmPassword');
  let spPasswordConfirmation = $('#spPasswordConfirmation');

  if (txtConfirmPassword.val() !== $('#txtPassword').val()) {
    txtConfirmPassword.val('');
    spPasswordConfirmation.html('Password and Retype Password does not match.');
  } else {
    spPasswordConfirmation.html('');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" value="" id="txtPassword">
  <br>
  <input type="text" value="" id="txtConfirmPassword">
  <br>
  <span id="spPasswordConfirmation"></span>
</form>
```